# What did I do wrong about building a js-function and connecting it in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I need to write a js-function to show some HTML blocks by clicking on a dropdown element. It just doesn't go. Can you help me please, what did I do wrong?

```js
function parameterOne(e) 
{
 e = event || window.event;
// $('div.checkboxes').style.display = "none";
 $('div.checkboxes:first-child').style.display = "block";
 $('h4#kriterium').style.display = "block";
 return true;
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #788bb6;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2C3459;
} */

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #788bb6; color:#fff;}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

label.checkbox {
 font-size: 13px;
 border: none;
}

div.checkboxes {
 margin-top: 15px;
 display: none;
}

h4#kriterium {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
     
     <div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="dropdown()" class="dropbtn">Leads auswählen (sonst alle)</button>
  <div id="Lead" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" onclick="parameterOne()" value="Click">Kriterium 1</a>
    <a href="#">Kriterium 2</a>
    <a href="#">Kriterium 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
<h4 id="kriterium">Kriterium 1</h4>
<div class="checkboxes">
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="1"> Wert 1</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="2"> Wert 2</label>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="3"> Wert 3</label>
</div>
```

I expect that the first div.checkboxes is shown by clicking on the first link in the menu, but the console shows these errors:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
>      at parameterOne (custom.js:49)
>      at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM7759 admin.html:156)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing vanilla Javascript and jQuery. Try this:

```
$('div.checkboxes:first-child').css('display', 'block')
```

More infos here: https://api.jquery.com/css/

If you want the Javascript way you should use js selectors (like `querySelector` or `getElementsBy...`). jQuery returns its own typoe of element but Js returns an HTMLCollection -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection